# Motivo para negativar uma resposta que soluciona o problema

Tags: debate

Hoje ao participar de uma pergunta que estava um tanto quanto abrangente segue ela no link ([[DIV Exibir texto ao passar o mouse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248039/div-exibir-texto-ao-passar-o-mouse/248045][1])),
minha resposta era o suficiente para solucionar o problema apresentado porem fui negativado, mas afinal oq é necessário para ter uma resposta decente ?
No caso minha resposta estava simples e direta

Comment: Nem todas as soluções que resolvem um problema são boas

Comment: @Isac , mas então se eu fizer uma resposta boa , porem que nao responde a pergunta direito ela merece receber um ponto ? acredito que na pergunta a gente procura respostas onde conseguimos aplica-las em nossos sistemas, se ela funciona mas em meu sistema não a culpa não é de quem respondeu mas sim as peculiaridades que meu sistema possui, na minha resposta por exemplo especifiquei que utilizaria jQuery e 1 linha de codigo ja seria o suficiente para solucionar o problema, na pergunta não estava dizendo q não podia usar o jQuery então a minha resposta era totalmente valida não é ?

Comment: Eu pessoalmente acho exagerado o negativo, assim como também acho exagerado utilizar JQuery para um problema que se resolve em 2 linhas de Javascript puro.

Comment: Outra coisa que não fez na sua pergunta é detalhar o que fez, explicar como fez. Repare que a sua resposta não tem nenhuma explicação a menos de dizer que usa JQuery, ao contrário da outra resposta que lá está

Comment: @Isac entendo, conforme a resposta que obtive aqui no debate percebi, onde foi minha "falha", que no caso foi a ausencia de detalhes para um entendimento completo do meu codigo

Comment: Eu acho que a resposta fugiu da pergunta. Embora a pergunta seja meio fraca, as tags marcadas dão uma dica clara de como deve ser respondida. A resposta sugeriu jQuery, que não faz parte das tags marcadas na pergunta. Podia ter perguntado ao AP nos comentários.

Comment: @DvD Em tempo: seu texto original está aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/137353 - pode ser reaproveitado numa tag "desambiguada", para não perder o esforço dispendido.

Comment: @DvD um dos nossos mods, o Sergio, criou um post novo convidando a comunidade a sugerir tags desambiguadas. Vou deletar os meus comments acima para não deixar bagunça aqui na postagem

Answer (score 4):

Não sei quais foram os conceitos aplicados pelos usúarios que te deram *Downvote*.

Mas considere sempre ler os comentários feitos na sua resposta e tentar **aprimorá-la**, busque sempre colocar além do código, uma explicação e se possível exemplo(s) e referências.

Além de você aprofundar seu conhecimento se permintindo conhecer novas e melhores soluções para um problema, você fará com que as pessoas reavaliem sua resposta, possibilitando a mudança de um *downvote* para um **upvote**.

Entrando no caso da sua resposta em questão, existem diversas formas de resolve-lo, segue abaixo um outro exemplo de solução possível:

Abaixo  utilizando apenas a propriedade [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display) do `CSS` em conjunto com [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:hover).

Inicialmente a `div` contendo texto estará "invisivel" assim que a presença do mouse for percebida ela será a propriedade de exibição será modificada:

```css
.corpo {
  width:200px;
  min-height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}

.corpo .conteudo {
    display: none;
}

.corpo:hover .conteudo {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="corpo">
  <div class="conteudo">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado , é que como a pergunta do rapaz estava muito abrangente e não tinha nenhum codigo nem nada do tipo tentei ser o mais simples possivel na minha resposta, vou utilizar sua sugestão na minha resposta

Answer (score 0):

Eu sempre foco nas tags da pergunta, e caso seja inviável, eu procuro perguntar nos comentários se o AP deseja uma solução fora das tags da pergunta. Geralmente, quando isso não é explícito na pergunta, eles aceitam.

Muitas vezes o AP, principalmente os com pouca experiência no site, fazem perguntas e relacionam tags à pergunta e esquecem de relacionar outras, ou até se confundem. Por isso é importante perguntar. Muitas vezes, eles botam a tag `javascript` e esquecem de botar `jquery`.

Acho que sua resposta foi boa, mas se antecipou em vários aspectos, criando `class`, `id` e outros métodos que o AP nem mencionou na pergunta. Embora a pergunta tenha sido muito vaga, a sua resposta poderia ser genérica, sem criar tais atributos à `div`.

Sem falar que a sua resposta muda todo o HTML da `div`, e não apenas um suposto texto dentro dela.